# Jira Webhook to Google Calendar API

Tags: google-calendar-api, jira, webhooks

I am having hard times figuring out how to create a JIRA webhook that creates a google calendar event after an ISSUE has been created in JIRA. 
Start and end times of this event should be taken from custom fields in that created Issue. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer. Avoid asking multiple distinct questions at once. See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may refer with this [documentation](https://github.com/juansanzone/jiraToGoogleCalendar). You will need to:

- Create and Configure your Jira Web Hook

  - https://developer.atlassian.com/display/JIRADEV/JIRA+Webhooks+Overview
- Create a Google API Server-Side app

  - https://developers.google.com/drive/web/auth/web-server
- Enable and set Google Calendar Scope

  - https://developers.google.com/drive/web/scopes
- Generate a OAuth2 Certificated Key (.p12) file

  - https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2ServiceAccount
- Get your Service Account Name for your Project from Developer Console

  - https://console.developers.google.com/project

You may also check this tutorial: [Google Calendar and Jira Integration](https://automate.io/integration/google-calendar/jira)

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!